# How is the time complexity of Bucket Sort O(n+k) if it uses insertion sort to sort each bucket?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

Since time complexity of insertion sort is O(n^2), how is the average case time complexity of bucket sort O(n+k) as it uses insertion sort at each bucket?
Here k is the number of buckets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort#Average-case_analysis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a look at the [detailed calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort#Average-case_analysis) of the average time-complexity. Although, here is an intuition.

First, in the worst-case, bucket sort is *O(n^2)*. This happens whenever all elements end up in the same buckets.

Although, bucket sort relies on elements being uniformly distributed across buckets. Given that assumption, and given a number of bucket proportional to the size of the input, then the average bucket should contain *O(1)* elements. In other words, by choosing enough buckets, you keep their size small.

This means the sorting of buckets has no effect toward the overall time-complexity. Choosing insertion sort then becomes a sensible choice as it has smaller overhead and requires no extra space.

Comment: Nice explanation.